# Translation of "you either speak too quickly or too slowly." without repeating 说

Tags: grammar, conjunction

[This answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/34518) gives an example sentence meaning "you speak too quickly" to illustrate the usage of `得 (·de)`.

```
1) 你说得太快了。
```

In order to say "you either speak too quickly or too slowly", I'm pretty sure it's possible to say (2). Although (2) might be analyzed as two separate clauses: a clause with an explicit subject and a clause with a null subject.

```
2) 你说得太快了或者说得太慢了。
```

I'm pretty sure sentence (3) is wrong. Is there another conjunction that can be used instead of`或者` that makes the sentence grammatical with the intended meaning of "you either speak too quickly or too slowly"? I added spaces to (3) for emphasis only.

```
*3) 你说得太快了 或者 得太慢了。
```

Comment: You can try: 你說得不是太快了就是太慢了。

Comment: @user-487 you should expand that into an answer and simultaneously explain the structure 不是X就是Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another conjunction that can be used instead of或者

[不是(A)就是(B)] = [If not (A) would then (B)] = [Either (A) or (B)]

"不是(A: 說得太快),就是(B: 說得太慢)"

"你不是說得太快, 就是說得太慢"  = "you either speaking too fast or speaking too slow"

"你不是說得太快, 就是太慢" = "you either speaking too fast or too slow"
(*omit the repeating verb*)

~

[有時(A),有時(B)] = [sometimes (A), sometimes (B)]

"有時(A:說得太快), 有時 (B:說得太慢)

"你有時說得太快, 有時說得太慢" = "you sometimes speaking too fast, something speaking too slow"

*The final particle 了 is optional*

Answer (score 1):

你说得不是太快就是太慢 is what I would say.